# SQL Syntax error with foreign keys

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

now i have table place `CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Place] (
    [Place_Id]      INT          IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Name]          VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [Building_Date] DATE         NULL,
    [Longitude]     VARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [Latitude]      VARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [Location]      VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Place_Id] ASC)
);` , and table Citeria `CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Criteria] (
    [Criteria] VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [Place_Id] INT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Criteria], [Place_Id]), CONSTRAINT [FK_Criteria_ToTable] FOREIGN KEY (Place_Id) REFERENCES Place(Place_Id)
);`and The referenced table '[dbo].[Criteria]' contains no primary or candidate keys that match the referencing column list in the foreign key. If the referenced column is a computed column, it should be persisted.
 .

Comment: you can't create a check constraint as a sql command. And you cant create two foreign keys to a composite primary key. try on you second example `CONSTRAINT [FK_Normal_Upload] FOREIGN KEY (User_Name) REFERENCES Likes(User_Name, Place_Id)` and remove the constraint added just for place_id

Comment: I removed the MySQL tag because the syntax is clearly SQL Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is correct.  Subqueries are not allowed in `check` constraints.

But, you already have a foreign key reference between `user_name` and `likes(user_name)`, so this condition is already in place.  The only thing is would really be checking is that `user_name` is not `NULL`, but that is already true by the definition of the column.

Now, there are other issues.  Your foreign keys should be to primary keys or unique keys in other tables.  I think this is your intention:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].Normal_Upload
(
    [User_Name] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL , 
    [Place_Id] INT NOT NULL, 
    [Image] IMAGE NOT NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Normal_Upload] FOREIGN KEY (User_Name) REFERENCES Member(User_Name), 
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Normal_Upload_1] FOREIGN KEY (Place_Id) REFERENCES Place(Place_Id), 
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Normal_Upload_2] FOREIGN KEY (User_Name, Place_Id) REFERENCES Likes(User_Name, Place_Id)
);
```

As a note on naming.  I think the primary keys of tables should include the table name.  So, consider `Member_Name` rather than `User_Name` for the `Member` table.

Answer (score 0):

It wrong db design, never use varchar or character type column in reference key or primary-key(try to avoid as much as possible).

For you solution, create a column "useid" with int datatype and give pk to it. and update the following table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Likes] (
    [User_id] VARCHAR (50) Identity (1,1),
    [User_Name] VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [Place_Id]  INT          NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Likes] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([User_id] ASC, [Place_Id] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Likes_ToTable] FOREIGN KEY ([User_Name]) REFERENCES Normal ([User_Name]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Likes_ToTable_1] FOREIGN KEY ([Place_Id]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Place] ([Place_Id]),

);
```